# Expect command not always printing output to file

Tags: bash, unix, tcl, expect

I have a `main_parent_script.sh` inside which I am calling one more `parent_script.sh` which has the below command:

`/usr/bin/expect sftp_pass.sh list 22 sample_user hostname.hc.uk pass@123 get/FOR_20210420125933_NOTIFICATION_HEADER.json.zip > /temp/src_list.txt`

Whenever I run the main parent script, it never populates the `src_list.txt` file. But when I run the sftp_pass.sh command separately, it populates the `src_list.txt` file correctly with below o/p:

```
-rwxrwxrwx    0 300096102 300096102      576 May 24 15:04 get/FOR_20210420125933_NOTIFICATION_HEADER.json.zip
sftp>
```

Also, I observed that the output is correctly populated when run by the main parent script, only when the output of ls command gives 2 or more files.

Below is the content of the sftp_pass.sh script:

```
log_user 0
##-------------Start of script----------------
set expectedcmd [lindex $argv 0]
set port [lindex $argv 1]
set user [lindex $argv 2]
set host [lindex $argv 3]
set pass [lindex $argv 4]

if {$expectedcmd=="list"} {
set file [lindex $argv 5]
spawn sftp -oPort=$port $user@$host
expect "password:"
send "$pass\n"
set prompt "sftp>";
set command "ls -l $file";
}
##---------------------------------
expect "$prompt"    ;# wait for prompt
send   "$command\r" ;# send command
expect "$command\r" ;# discard command echo
log_user 1
sleep 5
expect -re "(.*)\r" ;# match and save the result
expect eof
send -- "exit\r"
##-------------End of script--------------------
```

I even tried to use a `log_file` to output the execution inside the script. But still I am having the same issue.

Comment: You're not showing the shell scripts, so we have no way to know why the output files are not populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
...

expect "$command\r" ;# discard command echo
expect *
send_user -- $expect_out(buffer)
log_user 1
sleep 5
expect -re "(.*)\r" ;# match and save the result
expect eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Some code review comments:

`expect eof` should be *after* `send exit` -- there's no error with the current placement, except that your script will "hang" for $timeout seconds waiting for the sftp connection to close, not see it, *then* send the exit command.

What happens if the first argument is *not* "list"? You will not `spawn` any process, but then expect a prompt.

You should not need to `sleep 5` if the expect patterns are correct.